# Media queries not working with styled components in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, styled-components

I'm having trouble getting media queries to work with media templates and styled components. I defined a MediaQueries template straight from the docs:

## MediaQueries.js

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

const sizes = {
  desktop: 992,
  tablet: 768,
  phone: 576
};

// Iterate through the sizes and create a media template
const media = Object.keys(sizes).reduce((acc, label) => {
  acc[label] = (...args) => css`
    @media (max-width: ${sizes[label] / 16}em) {
      ${css(...args)}
    }
  `;

  return acc;
}, {});

export default media;
```

And here's the test file:

## App.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import media from "./MediaQueries";

const Desktop = styled.h1`
  color: red;

  ${media.phone`
    display: none;
  `}
`;

const Mobile = styled.h1`
  color: blue;

  ${media.desktop`
    display: none;
  `}
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Mobile>Mobile</Mobile>
      <Desktop>Desktop</Desktop>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What I'm expecting is for the [Desktop] title to be shown on large screens, and [Mobile] to be shown on smaller ones.

What I'm getting is the opposite: I get both titles on large screens, then while shrinking the window [Mobile] disappears first, then [Desktop].

My goal is to have one and only one of the components visible at all times. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you got the rules mixed. If you want to toggle them based on size then one of them should start off with `display:none`, then you switch them.

Something similar to this:

```
const Desktop = styled.h1`
  color: red;

  ${media.phone`
    display: none;
  `}
`;

const Mobile = styled.h1`
  color: blue;
  display: none;
  ${media.phone`
    display: block;
  `}
`;
```

Comment: Follow-up: is there a reason why if I design for desktop and add media.phone everything works, but not the other way around? Do I have to follow that order given my code, or is there a way to make both ways work?

Comment: When you check for `max-width` then this is the way to go IMO

Comment: So if I check `max-width` i have to go from large to small, and with `min-width`  from small to large?

Comment: This is the rule of thumb that i use. Though I'm not considering myself as an expert on that manner 

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers

Comment: No problem, glad it help 