# React styled component media query not working with child elements?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So I have this styled component where I target nested images to position them individually. I want to add a media query on the main component, but when I do this above the nested images, it gives me a syntax error.

Here is my styled component

```
      const ColumnRight = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        position: relative;

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          height: 100vh;
        }

        ${Image}:nth-child (1) {
          top: 10px;
          left: 10px;
        }
        `
```

This code is what causes my error

```
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          height: 100vh;
        }
```

If I just do this, it works completely fine.

```
  const ColumnRight = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        position: relative;

        ${Image}:nth-child (1) {
          top: 10px;
          left: 10px;
        }
        `
```

Here are the components I'm trying to target

```
   <ColumnRight>
      <Image/>
   </ColumnRight>
```

Why does it work completely fine when I don't include a media query, but right when I add it, it causes a syntax error?

[image]

Update: I found the issue is that prettier adds a space randomly to my nth-childs when I save, which causes the error.

So the code on save ends up doing this

```
  nth-child  (1)
```

When it should just be `nth-child(1)`

Any idea why this occurs and how to prevent it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media queries not working with styled components in React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304094/media-queries-not-working-with-styled-components-in-react-app)

Comment: nah still shows a syntax error cause I have the nested childs

Comment: What is Image.... Is it also a styled component?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this?

```js
  const ColumnRight = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        position: relative;

        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          height: 100vh;
        }

        > ${Image}:nth-child(1) {
          top: 10px;
          left: 10px;
        }
`
```

Comment: still not working. I added a pic of the error above

Comment: actually whenever I save it, it adds a space between the nth-child and the (1) which is why the error occurs. Do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: @Johnxr Which version of the prettier are you using now? It seems fixed for similar [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5961) in May. Please check it out.